# Running tests multiple times with different fixtures

Tags: clojure

If I pass `use-fixtures` multiple fixtures, it will close over them one after another:

```
(def ^:dynamic *path* nil)

(defn sun [f]
  (println "sun setup" *path*)
  (binding [*path* "sun"]
    (f))
  (println "sun cleanup"))

(defn rain [f]
  (println "rain setup" *path*)
  (binding [*path* "rain"]
    (f))
  (println "rain cleanup"))

(use-fixtures :once sun rain)

(deftest sometest1
         (println "sometest1" *path*))

(deftest sometest2
         (println "sometest2" *path*))

(run-tests)

Testing scratchpad.core
sun setup nil
rain setup sun
sometest1 rain
sometest2 rain
rain cleanup
sun cleanup
```

This is useful but how to do instead something like:

```
Testing scratchpad.core
sun setup nil
sometest1 sun
sometest2 sun
sun cleanup
rain setup nil
sometest1 rain
sometest2 rain
rain cleanup
```

Comment: Also, is there a reason you are favoring binding over with-redefs?

Comment: Do you want to test different implementations, or one implementation under different contexts? Are the entire tests equal for evey context? I would expect the contexts to share common behavior but also to exhibit some differences

Comment: @RedDeckWins - No, this is just an example to show the point.

Comment: @nberger - This is a theoretical situation and I want to test one implementation under different contexts with equal tests for every context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not try to do that with clojure.test fixtures. From an old (but still current in many aspects) [post by Stuart Sierra](http://stuartsierra.com/2010/07/05/lazytest-status-report):

> **Fixtures can only be assigned per-namespace**. Fixtures were a late
> addition to clojure.test and were not integrated well with the rest of
> the design. The fact that they are globally applied to an entire
> namespace makes them useless for all but the simplest cases.

Don't want them globally applied to your entire namespace? You'll need a different solution. I would look for something that:

1. In case of an error, the output shows in which context it occurred.
2. Allows for differences on what is tested in each context. You'll probably want to test some common behavior but also specifics to each context.
3. Favors explicitness (locals) over "magic" (globals)

### Proposed solution

Use the `testing` macro wrapped in a function to define the common tests, and a `deftest` for each context to do the test setup, run common & specifics tests, and finally the cleanup:

```
(defn path-test [path]
  (testing "test1"
    (println "sometest1" path))
  (testing "test2"
    (println "sometest2" path)))

(deftest sun-test
  (println "sun setup")
  (let [path "sun"]
    (path-test "sun")
    (is (= :warm (get-temperature path))))
  (println "sun cleanup"))

(deftest rain-test
  (println "rain setup")
  (let [path "rain"]
    (path-test "rain")
    (is (= :wet (get-floor path))))
  (println "rain cleanup"))
```

An example of this technique can be seen in the ["callable-contexts" in thi-ng.geom tests](https://github.com/thi-ng/geom/blob/master/geom-core/test/core.org#callable-contexts).

Another strategy is to play around with `test-ns-hook`. You can find an example [here](https://twoguysarguing.wordpress.com/2010/03/24/fixies/).

Both strategies work if you want to test multiple implementations, or one implementation under multiple contexts.

Comment: Thank you so much for the proposed solution and the provided links - it was a good read.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a short function that will do what you want, juxt-fixtures.  hopefully this works for you.

```
(def ^:dynamic *path* nil)

(defn sun [f]
  (println "sun setup" *path*)
  (binding [*path* "sun"]
    (f))
  (println "sun cleanup"))

(defn rain [f]
  (println "rain setup" *path*)
  (binding [*path* "rain"]
    (f))
  (println "rain cleanup"))

(defn juxt-fixtures [& fixtures]
  (fn [f]
    (->> ((apply juxt fixtures) f)
         dorun)))

(use-fixtures :once (juxt-fixtures sun rain))

(deftest sometest1
  (println "sometest1" *path*))

(deftest sometest2
  (println "sometest2" *path*))
```

And the output:

```
sun setup nil
sometest2 sun
sometest1 sun
sun cleanup
rain setup nil
sometest2 rain
sometest1 rain
rain cleanup
```

Comment: I do not understand why not just simply do `(use-fixtures :once (juxt sun rain))`? The result is the same.

Comment: I wasn't sure if juxt was lazy or not, so I made a short function to wrap it and perform a dorun.

Comment: I see what you are saying. It's not lazy, returned function returns a vector.